# Gregorian to Noxu Time System Conversion

Tags: code-golf, math

The world's changing to a new time system!  We need to update our computer programs.  Given an input of epoch time (number of seconds since January 1st, 1970 00:00), print out a time in the new Noxu date-time format.

864 seconds make one Fluffster.  100 Fluffsters make a Skizzle.  There are 4 Skizzles in one Zestpond.  Their names are Looplab, Sevit, Hexteria, and Sinpad.  There are 91 Zestponds in one Lulerain.

The format is Lulerain Zestpond-Skizzle-Fluffster.  Fluffsters are rounded to two decimal places.  An example would be `50 13-Sevit-40.90`.

Given that epoch 0 was `0 0-Looplab-00.00`, create a program that takes input either via stdin or as a command line argument of any epoch time between 0 and 2^32, and prints out the Noxu equivalent.

#### Time of edit:

```
1357510372 -> 43 14-Sinpad-92.56
```

#### Random test data:

```
675416077 -> 21 43-Sevit-31.57
330585453 -> 10 46-Hexteria-22.05
1328127085 -> 42 20-Sinpad-84.13
837779784 -> 26 58-Looplab-52.53
1240280676 -> 39 39-Sinpad-10.04
122646385 -> 3 81-Sinpad-51.83
1311245658 -> 41 63-Looplab-45.44
57792972 -> 1 76-Looplab-90.01
788388068 -> 25 6-Looplab-86.19
304341865 -> 9 61-Hexteria-47.53
417857784 -> 13 26-Looplab-31.69
671276878 -> 21 31-Sevit-40.83
1259758896 -> 40 5-Looplab-54.28
604286664 -> 19 19-Hexteria-5.86
646395018 -> 20 50-Sevit-42.38
563025133 -> 17 82-Looplab-49.46
96133144 -> 3 5-Looplab-65.21
101542552 -> 3 20-Sinpad-26.10
1006825856 -> 32 1-Sevit-7.70
928867348 -> 29 48-Hexteria-77.95
1235022079 -> 39 24-Hexteria-23.70
439505287 -> 13 88-Hexteria-86.67
99686711 -> 3 15-Sevit-78.14
379859609 -> 12 7-Looplab-52.33
1167091685 -> 37 10-Looplab-0.56
612032437 -> 19 41-Sinpad-70.88
503040778 -> 15 90-Hexteria-23.12
1084809411 -> 34 44-Sinpad-66.45
1105664386 -> 35 14-Sevit-4.15
197303893 -> 6 24-Sinpad-60.99
368559287 -> 11 65-Sevit-73.25
686824300 -> 21 76-Sevit-35.53
196468204 -> 6 22-Sevit-93.75
673542185 -> 21 37-Sinpad-62.71
993063782 -> 31 52-Sevit-79.38
270951743 -> 8 56-Looplab-1.55
1074506753 -> 34 15-Looplab-42.08
198143696 -> 6 27-Sevit-32.98
539601298 -> 17 14-Sevit-38.54
110090607 -> 3 45-Hexteria-19.68
276492708 -> 8 72-Looplab-14.71
113389138 -> 3 55-Looplab-37.43
571578220 -> 18 15-Sinpad-48.87
1238516450 -> 39 34-Hexteria-68.11
742293312 -> 23 54-Sinpad-35.78
1031929490 -> 32 73-Sinpad-62.84
503091914 -> 15 90-Hexteria-82.31
264094386 -> 8 36-Looplab-64.80
483820698 -> 15 34-Sinpad-77.66
548410387 -> 17 39-Sinpad-34.24
```

Comment: Could you please post a test set?

Comment: @belisarius, I added some :-)

Comment: @belisarius, I made a typo in my post.  It's supposed to be 864 instead of 846.  Should be a simple fix in your code.  I updated the test data and description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## dc - 81

```
2k864/0k100~[Looplab]0:a[Sevit]1:a[Hexteria]2:a[Sinpad]3:ar4~;ar91~rn32Pn45dPrnPp
```

Expects the epoch time already on the stack so invoke as, e.g.

```
dc -e `date +%s` -e '2k864/0k100~[Looplab]0:a[Sevit]1:a[Hexteria]2:a[Sinpad]3:ar4~;ar91~rn32Pn45dPrnPp'
```

to get the current Noxu time or add one character to accept the time from stdin

```
?2k864/0k100~[Looplab]0:a[Sevit]1:a[Hexteria]2:a[Sinpad]3:ar4~;ar91~rn32Pn45dPrnPp
```

### annotated version

```
2 k             # set the precision to 2 decimal places
864 /           # divide the number of seconds by 864 to get fluffsters
0 k             # set the precision back to 0 decimal places
100 ~           # divrem by 100; fluffsters are at the top skizzles under it
[Looplab] 0 :a  # set a[0] to the string Looplab
[Sevit] 1 :a    # set a[1] to Sevit
[Hexteria] 2 :a # set a[2] to Hexteria
[Sinpad] 3 :a   # set a[3] to Sinpad
r               # swap fluffsters and skizzles on the stack
4 ~             # divrem the skizzles by 4; skizzles on top zestpond under it
;a              # use the skizzle as an index into a
r               # swap the skizzle string and zestponds
91 ~            # divrem the zestponds by 91; zestponds on top lulerain under
r               # swap zestponds and lulerains
# now the stack has (from top to bottom)
# lulerains
# zestponds
# skizzle (as the name)
# fluffster
n               # pop and print the lulerains (without a newline)
32 P            # print a space character
n               # pop and print the zestponds
45 d P          # print a - and leave 45 on the top of the stack
r               # swap the 45 and the skizzle name
n               # pop and print the skizzle name
P               # print a - from the 45 that was on the stack
p               # finally print the fluffster (with a newline)
```

When the number of fluffsters is less than 1 there is no leading zero printed, to get the leading zero, it is

```
2k864/0k100~[Looplab]0:a[Sevit]1:a[Hexteria]2:a[Sinpad]3:ar4~;ar91~rn32Pn45dPrnPd[0n]sb1>bp
```

at a cost of 10 extra characters (`d[0n]sb1>b`)

Answer (score 4):

## APL, 87

```
t[3]←(1+3⌷t←137 91 4 100⊤⍎2⍕⎕÷864)⌷'Looplab' 'Sevit' 'Hexteria' 'Sinpad'
'  '⎕R'-'⍕t
```

APL has an advantage in these time system conversion challenges due to the built-in encode function, at the cost of expensive string manipuation

**Explanation**
(using `1357510372` as example)

`⎕÷864` takes user input from screen, divide by 864 (`1571192.56018519`)
`⍎2⍕` and round to 2 dp.  (`1571192.56`)
`137 91 4 100⊤` Then, converts to Noxu Time System (`43 14 3 92.56`)
`t←` and assign that to variable `t`.
`1+3⌷` take the 3rd item from `t`, add 1 to account for 1-based indexing, (`4`)
`(`...`)⌷'Looplab' 'Sevit' 'Hexteria' 'Sinpad'` convert to Skizzle name, (`Sinpad`)
`t[3]←` and finally plug back into the 3rd item of `t`.

`⍕t` Convert `t` to a string representation, (`43 14  Sinpad  92.56`)
`'  '⎕R'-'` and replaces 2 spaces with a dash (`43 14-Sinpad-92.56`)

Comment: Very impressive!

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Actually this doesn't force 2 dp (So input `0` gives `0 0-Looplab-0`). If you insist on it, it would cost 23 chars.

Comment: Or, as some of the tests don't include a leading zero in case of Fluffster < 10, it would cost 22 chars instead.

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica 152

Still has some format issues. Spaces added for clarity

```
Flatten@{#[[5]], {Looplab, Sevit, Hexteria,  Sinpad}[[#[[4, 2]] + 1]], 
        N[#[[3, 2]] + #[[2, 2]]/864, 4]} &@
               FoldList[QuotientRemainder[#1[[1]], #2] &, {#, 0}, {864, 100, 4, 91}]&
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 123

```
x=input()
b=86400
c=b*4
d=c*91
print x/d,'%d-%s-%.2f'%(x%d/c,['Looplab','Sevit','Hexteria','Sinpad'][x%d%c/b],x%d%c%b/864.)
```

Comment: Nice work.  It used 6 lines; I wonder if it could be condensed any more.

Comment: `a=864.` will save two chars on the print line, i believe (you can remove the `*1./a` and just have `/a`). Just set `b` to 86400 instead of `a*100`.

Comment: I don't see why you can't just inline `a`

Answer (score 2):

### **Ruby, <s>114</s> 112**

```
x=gets.to_f
puts'%d %d-%s-%.2f'%[x/d=91*c=4*b=86400,(x%=d)/c,%w[Looplab Sevit Hexteria Sinpad][x%c/b],x%c%b/864]
```

Meh. Basically grc's solution but with inline assignments.

Edit: Saved 2 chars by changing `to_i` to `to_f` so I don't need the float literal later.